# Show all includes in a rendered page (Template Path Hints)

Tags: magento-1.7, template, design

What simple method can I use to print then name to the browser of each file being loaded to render a particular page? I'm trying to develop, and it sure would be helpful if there was a method by which to output each file in a debug mode.

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and find a solid reputable debugging extension (there are several). I'll plug nobody specific here, as they kind of do basically the same thing. Very useful.

Comment: I would, but I only have access to the app/design/frontend and skin/frontend directories in this case. Otherwise I'd set everything in in NetBeans + xdebug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about template blocks, there is a highlight mechanism in **System Configuration**. Go down to the bottom of the left hand navigation and look for **Developer**.

```
System Configuration => Developer => Debug
    Template Path Hints
    Add Block Names to Hints
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have that. My only option under Debug is Profiler.

Comment: Go to the top left and change the scope till you have the options.

Comment: Yes, this worked. Also had to add my IP address to the whitelist. Thanks!